# Rows from tsv file into separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I have some motion capture data, so specific values relating to specific markers. What I want to do is read only specific rows and columns from this tsv file and place those values into arrays.

My data - the t_0028.tsv file - looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to keep the values from row 12 onwards, considering the columns corresponding to the markers (eg. ARIEL_01 X, ARIEL_01 Y, ARIEL_01 Z).

So the desired output would be:
`ARIEL_01_X = [##, ##, ## .. ]` where the # are the values.

I started to do this like so:

```
with open("t_0028.tsv") as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter="\t")
    for row in rd:
        print(row[10:21])
```

But the output is just the whole tsv document. I haven't considered how to put them into arrays like I want them, honestly I don't know how to do that, or even if it's possible.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you post a sample of "t_0028.tsv" ?

Comment: Are you able to install and use Pandas in your Python environment? It is rather easy to get what you want using Pandas.

Comment: @Jona The photo above is an example of t_0028.tsv

Comment: @imran yes, I can use Pandas, I'm working on Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your input is a tsv file and that its image through Excel is what you have shown, you should:

- skip the 11 initial lines
- consider only the relevant columns

Code could be:

```
ARIEL_01_X = []
ARIEL_01_Y = []
ARIEL_01_Z = []
with open("t_0028.tsv") as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter="\t")
    for i in range(11): _ = next(rd)           # skip initial lines
    for row in rd:
        ARIEL_01_X.append(row[3])              # only keep the relevant columns
        ARIEL_01_Y.append(row[4])
        ARIEL_01_Z.append(row[5])
```

Comment: Thank you for this..The only issue is now the array looks like this `ARIEL_01_X 
 = ['-205.981',
 '-206.203',
 '-206.376',...]`
 Is there a way to not have the  ' ' around each value?

Answer (score 1):

Using Pandas, this is quite easy, basically one line of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("t_0028.tsv", sep="\t", skiprows=10)
df['ARIEL_01 X'] 
# or 
df['ARIEL_01 X'].tolist()
```

If you want to only keep certain columns in the dataframe, you can pass somthing like `usecols=['Frame','ARIEL_01 X','ARIEL_01 Y','ARIEL_01 Z']` to the `read_csv` method.